# Header Manager missing Authorization bearer token

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter

Token is generated and stored as ${token} variable but when i check Result Tree for login Authorization header is missing, same as value. What's wrong? Error in project structure?

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah9sa.png)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot stay "what's wrong" without seeing your HTTP Header Manager setup so I can provide only generic piece of advice:

1. Make sure that your `token` variable exists and has its respective value, it can be done using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)
2. If your variable is fine - make sure to manually add it to the HTTP Header Manager as an [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header like:

   [image]